# Issue with HashiCorp Nomad v1.4.5: Template Rendering Error for raw_exec Task

Tags: nomad

Hello,

I'm working with HashiCorp Nomad version 1.4.5 and facing an issue with a raw_exec task. The task is meant to loop through an array and print its elements. Here's my Nomad job configuration:

```
variable "datacenter" {
  type        = string
  description = "Consul datacenter"
  default     = "cellebrite"
}


job "loop" {
  datacenters = [var.datacenter]
  type        = "batch"

  group "loop" {

    count=2

    constraint {
      attribute = "${node.class}"
      operator  = "regexp"
      value     = "sdl_translation_engine.*"
    }

    task "prepare-sdl" {
      driver = "raw_exec"

      config {
        command = "local/loop.sh"
      }

      template {
        destination = "local/loop.sh"
        data = <<EOH
          #!/bin/sh
          set -ex       
          
            # Declare an array
            fruits=("apple" "banana" "cherry" "date" "fig")
            
            # Loop through the array elements
            for fruit in "${fruits[@]}"; do
                echo "I like $fruit"
            done

        EOH
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to submit this job, I receive the following error:

```
Error getting job struct: Error parsing job file from sdl/loop_bash.nomad:
loop_bash.nomad:39,36-37: Invalid character; This character is not used within the language., and 1 other diagnostic(s)
```

Few notes:

1. I have verified the syntax and structure of my Nomad job file.
2. I've confirmed that the Bash script runs successfully when executed directly, without Nomad.
3. I've confirmed that the job runs successfully when omitting the for loop.

I understand there is some issue with the nomad template trying to redner the loop
but I'm unable to identify the root cause of this error.
Any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> in "${fruits[@]}"; do
> ```

`${...}` are interpolated by Nomad https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/runtime/interpolation and https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/hcl2/expressions#string-templates . You have to escape it. Do:

```
for fruit in "$${fruits[@]}"; do
```

I typically store the script in a separate file. Check the following:

```
template {
   dest = "local/script.sh"
   # ./script.sh is relative to your _shell_ current working directory
   # relative to the directory you are _running_ nomad command line tool.
   # Separate file allows checking scripts easy with shellcheck.
   data = file("./script.sh")
   # You can't run the script without permissions.
   perms = "755"
   # Templates are consul-templated. Use unique delimiters. 
   # I typically use output from uuidgen
   left_delimiter = "cee4faf9-64fb-45f2-af88-96e70902bc63"
   right_delimiter = "82930c45-c997-4018-8d1d-50f9cc4fd420"
}
config {
   # You do not know where is local/. Use env variable.
   command = "${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/script.sh"
}
```

Additionally, check your script with shellcheck. `#!/bin/sh` has no arrays, arrays are a bash thing.

Comment: Now the nomad job is being parsed well but got driver failure error:
failed to launch command with executor: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start command path="/opt/nomad/data/alloc/50dcbcbd-f939-d1c5-01f7-526081eb4946/prepare-sdl/local/loop.sh" --- args=["/opt/nomad/data/alloc/50dcbcbd-f939-d1c5-01f7-526081eb4946/prepare-sdl/local/loop.sh"]: fork/exec /opt/nomad/data/alloc/50dcbcbd-f939-d1c5-01f7-526081eb4946/prepare-sdl/local/loop.sh: exec format error

Comment: `exec format error` you did not add `perms="755"` or you added invalid shebang. That's why it's better to do `sh ./script` instead of `./script`, so that you know you are running sh. Consider `command = "sh" args = ["${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/script.sh"
]`.

Comment: The issue was that I forgot #!/bin/sh.
Thank you, works now

Comment: Note that bash arrays are part of bash, not sh. You might want `#!/bin/bash`, not sh.